# siunitx package gives an error message

Tags: siunitx

I try to type some units in my LaTeX document but somehow it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[
    polutonikogreek,
    latin,
    english,
    french,
    ngerman,
        ]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        locale=DE,
        per-mode=fraction,
        separate-uncertainty,
        exponent-to-prefix,
        prefixes-as-symbols=false,
        list-units=brackets,
        range-units=brackets,
        multi-part-units=brackets,
        table-unit-alignment=left,
        load=prefixed,
        load-configurations=abbreviations,
    }
\begin{document}
    \SI{1}{\hectopascal}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. There is no command `\hectopascal`. Try `\hecto\pascal` instead and it will work ...

Comment: Hecto pascal is not a single unit. It is an amount and a unit (two macros). Please refer to the package manual.

Comment: so there is no easy way to write hPa because with \hecto\pascal it will appear as {1*10^2 Pa}

Comment: Have you got any reason for `prefixes-as-symbols=false`?

Answer (score 4):

Global options can be overwritten locally in the optional argument of `\SI`:

```
\SI[prefixes-as-symbols]{1}{\hecto\pascal}
```

Full file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        locale=DE,
        per-mode=fraction,
        separate-uncertainty,
        exponent-to-prefix,
        prefixes-as-symbols=false,
        list-units=brackets,
        range-units=brackets,
        multi-part-units=brackets,
        table-unit-alignment=left,
        % load=prefixed,
        load-configurations=abbreviations,
    }
\begin{document}
    \SI[prefixes-as-symbols]{1}{\hecto\pascal}

    \SI[prefixes-as-symbols]{1}{\micro\meter} =
    \SI[exponent-to-prefix=false]{e-6}{\meter} =
    \SI[exponent-to-prefix=false]{1}{\micro\meter}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: If I want  0.65 °K/100 m can I do that like this: `code`\SI{0.65}{\SIUnitSymbolDegree F}$\per$\SI{100}{\m}`code` Because with this way the "/" is not shown

Comment: @starter `\per` cannot be used outside of the macros of package `siunitx`. But a normal `/` or `\slash` (which allows line break) will do (in text mode, math mode not needed).

Comment: Does someone know how to write 10^-6 µm. I'm not able to type in the -6 in the exponent. `code` \SI[prefixes-as-symbols]{10}{\micro\m}

Comment: @starter See updated answer.